# India issues NOTAM for Very Long range Ballistic Missile Test

Tags: notam, china, india

- [India issues NOTAM for Very Long range Ballistic Missile Test](https://idrw.org/india-issues-notam-for-very-long-range-ballistic-missile-test/)

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Why does India need such a long and huge area?
2. Did China ever do this?

   - If not, why does India need this?

[image]

Comment: what is the relevance of China's behaviour? how are these questions Aviation.SE-related?

Comment: I agree, there is no relevance of this NOTAM to what China does or doesnt. Especially not for aviation.se. Any answer to this part of the question would be speculation.

Comment: *"Why does India need such a long and huge area?"* Might want to revisit the definition of "ballistic missile" :)

Comment: It's in that time window as of writing of this comment, and according to Flightradar24, there are literally planes flying through that region as if they couldn't care less.

Answer (score 6):

As for why India needs such a large and wide area, they are launching a missile, and what goes up is going to come down somewhere in that area. They have a wide area in case missile goes off course. It's good practice for a nation to warn people of potential dangers in the air from rocket testing.